# GraphQL two image transforms for same field

Tags: assets, graphql

To get image transform in GraphQL we use this

```
image {
   url @transform ([width: 300, immediately: true])
}
```

But how do I get two different image transforms (for responsive image) for this asset field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but should work:

```
image {
   foo: url @transform ([width: 300, immediately: true])
   boo: url @transform ([width: 600, immediately: true])
}
```

You can rename fields by just adding a new field name (ex `foo:`) before it in graphQL. The field name should not be one the object already has as it would overwrite the original field in this case.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.